# is time API dot org one hour ahead?

Tags: amazon-s3

is timeapi one hour ahead from the others sites, like these?

http://time.is/UTC

I was using this API to send files to S3. Two Months before now I started with problems about time differences.

time API: [timeapi.org](http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now?format=%25a%2C%20%25d%20%25b%20%25Y%20%25H:%25M:%25S%20GMT)

Comment: this is what I tried: http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now?format=%25a%2C%20%25d%20%25b%20%25Y%20%25H:%25M:%25S%20GMT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup. /utc/now is is off by one hour. At the moment, it is returning

```
2015-08-19T01:58:07+01:00
```

(notice the +01:00)

http://chronic.herokuapp.com returns

```
2015-08-19 00:57:27 +00:00
```

timeapi.org is based on an out of date fork of https://github.com/zh/timeapi, which is the basis for the heroku app linked above.

Answer (score 0):

It could be your local summer daylight saving has started.

I checked with mine time on time.is it's fine no time difference.